# How to fix connection timeout after 30001 seconds error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to found the pay.nl api code from https://github.com/paynl/sdk/blob/master/README.md.its works perfectly in local.but it is not working server..it gives this error:

fatal error: Uncaught Paynl\Error\Error: Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds ..can u pls give me any idea why is this error comes...

Comment: Can you do a normal `file_get_contents('http://httpbin.org/get')`, or does it time out also? Thinking firewall egress rules...

Comment: Curl is used to get the banks  by  pay.nl  api

Comment: Yeah but can your site do outbound api calls, that's why i asked you to test on a working site. If it cant then its not the api its your server. If it can perhaps its something else..